Newly connected devices within the same router cannot connect to other devices that were already connected
I have a media server setup running on a ubuntu 24.04 server. I am using a netlink gpon router as a router to connect to the internet as well as connect my devices to the server using wlan. The problem is that sometimes when I try to connect to my server from some devices I am unable to do so or the host is unreachable.

When a device gets re/connected to the wlan the device is unable to connect to other devices for a certain period of time. When I try pinging to some devices already connected to the network I get From <my_ip> icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable most of the time. But the ping succeeds within anywhere from 30 to 290 pings if I continue pinging.
Even then the new device can only connect to the device which it established connection by pinging and not other devices on the network.
(I don't know if it is normal behaviour but if I was actively using the device connected to the server and I briefly disconnects and reconnects the device to the network and then try pinging I get a packet loss of about 5 packets and then the connection succeeds)
Once I try to ping the new device from the already existing device(Server) in the network the new device can instantly connect to the existing device.
I also tried keeping my PC as my existing device and disconnected my server from the network and then reconnected it, and the server too has to ping the device continuously to the existing device(PC) to connect to it but the PC can instantly connect to it if the PC now pings the server.

My wlan encryption was set to WPA2 Mixed with WPA TKIP enabled so I changed it to WPA2 following the answer by @Spiff in Cannot ping some devices on my network, but doing it didn't fix it either.
I have already tried tweaking the firewall and Dos protection setting, resetting my router etc. My firewall is now set to low and Dos protection is disabled.
Don't know if it is relevant, when I checked the connected clients list I could see a column expired time for all clients, set to 300 sec.
Is there any solutions or workarounds to this problem(like repeatedly pinging the devices on my network with an interval from the server using static ip for all clients)?
Here are my wifi settings:
Lan Settings
Wlan
Wlan basic
Wlan security
Wlan active
Edit: I have done more testing and it appears that it might not be like the connection to other devices always succeeds after a certain number of pings as now the new devices being connected to the network are not able to ping the server even after 700 pings(after that I cancelled the operation).

Have you intentionally disabled your 5.0 GHz capability?

I suspect your router needs to be set to Bridge mode instead of Access Point mode but that definitely will disable WiFi on that device, which suggests netlink gpon router should be in Bridge mode allowing the device in the screenshots to be set to AP mode

How does that "band" pop-up work on your device? Is it telling you that you only have 2.4GHz enabled instead of having both 2.4GHz and 5GHz enabled simultaneously? For 2.4GHz settings, you should set it for 20MHz-wide channel only (no auto 20/40 or 40-only), and set it manually for the cleanest channel out of 1, 6, or 11 (use a network scanner like inSSIDer to find the cleanest channel). If I were you I'd also try switching 802.11w mode to optional, not required. Unless you know all your clients support 802.11w, it's probably best no to require it. But definitely make sure 5GHz is enabled!

Is there a bot marking all answers -1 somewhere, without explanation?  I just posted this minutes ago.  Is someone PO'd that AI are training on from this website (that's what I heard)?

@Ramhound No, my router only has 2.4GHz capability, the rest of the options are B,G,N settings. Also there is no Bridge mode in the mode settings, AP is the only available option. Bridge mode is available only in the Internet tab of the network settings tab. The available options there are Router and Bridge

@Spiff My router only has 2.4GHz capability, the rest of the options are B,G,N settings. I have now changed the channel width to 20MHz only and set channel to 11. The 802.11w was in capable by default and as it was not working I changed it to required. Now I have set it to capable and for the sha256 option that now appeared I set it to disabled. The issue still persists.

@Spiff Could it be that already connected device's network connection are going to sleep or something. I am asking as when I connect two devices to the network the new two devices are able to talk to each other instantly but pinging the server which is already in the network doesn't work.

@HansSchulze - “Is there a bot marking all answers -1 somewhere, without explanation?” - I am absolutely not a bot.

@Nidheesh - 802.11w does not exist and WiFi 4 supports 5 GHz
